# Make a button that adapts its size to the text it contains in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, size

I need the buttons in the following code to resize in order to fit in the text properly. How is it possible? Currently is the text all_definitions_list[0] is wider than the button then the texts gets cropped up.

```
choice1=Button(newWindow, text=all_definitions_list[0], height=5, width=50, 
command=lambda:wut(choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, wordLabel))
choice1.place(relx=0.5, rely=y_list[0], anchor=N)
```

Comment: ***"resize in order to fit in the text properly"***: Don't use the argument `width=50`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the argument width=50